# How to know the position of specific word or letter in paragraph without distortion when zooming

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, text

```
<body>
        <div style="position: relative; white-space: 'pre-wrap'">
            <div style="position:'absolute; top:'152'+'px';left:15+'px', height:'25px';width:'40px';border-radius:'50%';border:'2px solid'"></div>
            // Here there is a div that is positioned absolute that generates circular line
            <p>
                1. I want to circle the number one at any time even if screen
                gets minimized or zoomed 
                
                2. I want to circle number two too. I
                styled Card.Body as relative and div as absolute. I manually
                checked the position of the numbers and I set top and left
                attributes. 
                
                3. Then I managed to put div using border radius 50%
                and it is rounded and put on top of numbers but when I zoom it
                moves from numbers. 
                
                4. please help
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: I think I need to make my question clear. there is number 1 in above paragraph. I will specify the position of it interms of its location inside paragraph in this case it is first in the paragraph. How can I get its position in the dom and style it without losing its position no matter how much I zoom in or out or in any case.

Comment: Still very much unclear, what you are even trying to ask here. _My_ first question would be, why this is text stuffed into a paragraph in the first place, and not a proper ordered list?

Comment: Regarding the question title: You can not really get the position of individual letters. You can only get the position of _elements_. If you know what font gets used, and how wide each glyph in that is, you can perhaps _calculate_ the position of a specific letter in a text node, but that will get complicated, and probably not be very precise to begin with. Wrapping those numbers into an element of their own might probably be your best bet here (for whatever you actually need to achieve in the end.)

Comment: I am working to highlight the numbers and letters which are used as thumbnails from paragraph to give nice user experience.

Comment: Still all unclear and vague, as could possibly be. No one here knows what "highlighting" means in your understanding, and how a plain text number could constitute a "thumbnail" for anything. Please go read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: sorry for vague but your answer "Wrapping those numbers into an element of their own might probably be your best bet here" is nice thing and I took it as a solution for my problem. Thanks.